# Froala Toolbar bug when change page with rails and turbolinks 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, froala

I use froala on my rails app fine. But I use turbolinks and I have a problem of compatibility :

I have a page with specific toolbar assigned by `elt.froalaEditor({toolbarContainer: 'mytoolbar', [others options...]});` but :

- when I refrech realy (F5) the page, froala toolbar works
- when I go on other page and come back (via turbolink so), when I return, toolbar stay empty... (form works but no toolbar), I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this : https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#installing-javascript-behavior ?

I just paste the intro :

> You may be used to installing JavaScript behavior in response to the
>   `window.onload`, `DOMContentLoaded`, or `jQuery` ready events. With
>   Turbolinks, these events will fire only in response to the initial
>   page load, not after any subsequent page changes. We compare two
>   strategies for connecting JavaScript behavior to the DOM below.

I suppose that froala listens an event that is no more dispatch during the navigation because on how turbolinks works.

Comment: yes I do. I can try to start froala manually from console long time after is loaded and no works too...